# Align div to bottom of image displayed on previous div

Tags: html, css

I need to setup a header with a logo on the left, and some bottoms on the bottom-right. The size of the header is unknown.
[image]

(Sorry for the mistake, I was trying to mean buttons and not bottoms)
So I have three divs: container div, logo div, buttons div.
If I set the container div to a fixed size, for example 30px, I can do this, setting the bottom div:

```
#container-div {
    position: relative;
}
#buttons-div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

But if I don't set a size on container  div, which actually is the real case, the buttons-div just disappear, I think because the parent div size is zero in this case.
How's the way to properly arrange this when the size of the logo div is just unknown?

Comment: Might help to see the html as well. Can you throw what you have into CodePen (http://www.codepen.com) and share that? At first glance with what I see here, I would suggest removing the `position: absolute;` from the #buttons-div style, as this will absolutely position the div _in the window_, so it's likely disappearing to the bottom right of your window, not the container div. Might not be the total fix, but that might be a good start.

Comment: Hah, in testing I seemed to have disproved my own theory, I forgot that the `position: relative;` of the parent div would affect the absolute positioning of the child. So disregard that previous suggestion, please. Still curious to see the whole code though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `min-height` of the `#buttons-div` to make it work.

Take a look at this

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/kotoyeqate/edit?html,css,output)

```
#container-div {
    position: relative;
    min-height:50px;
}
#buttons-div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width:60%;

}

li{
  float:left;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style:none;
}
```